# Passing array to UIViewController and memory warning

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am receiving memory warning when passing mutable array from one view controller to another.
Any better way passing mutable array to uiviewcontroller?
//memory warning here.

```
Item *item = [self.items objectAtIndex:index ];
```

Comment: A viewController=>save Array in file .B viewController=>read Arry from file

Comment: Can you post code related to passing array to view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to pass a NSMutableArray From ViewController A to B is to do it in the segue from ViewControllerA

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Some segue"]) 
    {

        [segue.destinationViewController setPassedArray:self.someMutableArray];
    }
}
```

And in your `ViewControllerB` add this to your `ViewControllerB.h` file

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *passedArray
```

Now when ever you navigate to `ViewControllerB` `someMutableArray` will be passed to ViewControllerB and set to `passedArray`

Answer (score 0):

when A controller push B controller you can serialization array.

```
 -(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
 {
     NSArray* array = .....
     [array addObject:obj];//obj have to implements NSCopying,NSCoding
     NSData *archiveCarPriceData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:array];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:archiveCarPriceData forKey:@"your key"];
 }
```

B controller:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   NSData *myEncodedObject = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"your key"];
   NSArray* array = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: myEncodedObject];
}
```

or you can save it in file

```
{
    //save arr to file
    NSArray* arr;
    [arr writeToFile:@"path" atomically:YES];
    //read arr from file
    arr = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:@"path"]
}
```